# Pass model value to controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do you pass this model value from view to the controller method?

View:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchMethod", "Home", new { area = "Timetables" }))
                               {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Sessionstateadminroot.CourseSearchPara)
                                <button type="submit" >Search</button>
                               }
```

Controller method:

```
[Route("SearchMethod/{searchpara=Test}")]
        public ActionResult SearchMethod(string searchpara) 
        {
```

Comment: have you tried `[HttpPost]` on your controller action?

Comment: Thank you for reply... [HttpPost] does not fix

Comment: you are using an area called Timetables, if your project structure doesn't reflect your area declaration, your controller and action methods won't be found.

Comment: If I don't use a model in the textbox the textbox works...but I want to try to use a model

Comment: what is CourseSearchPara? is that a string or an object you are using? You need to show how you are passing the model from your controller to the view.

Comment: This is the problem. I don't know how to pass the model to the controller...If I change public ActionResult SearchMethod(string searchpara) to this public ActionResult SearchMethod(CourseServiceRef.SessionStateAdmin model) then the parameter is not passed. My model contains 2 models...Maybe I should use partial views?

Comment: I was asking about passing the model *from* the Controller to the view not the other way around.

Comment: Passing from controller to view is okay. The textbox contains the data, that is, the search term. So as the user is paging (post back to server) the search term is maintained in the box. The problem is...when the user types in a search term it does not get passed to controller. I am testing the app, and manually added the search term to db to see if it will pass from controller to view, and it does.

Comment: There is progress...the method is reached, but fails when I try to pass value from model to a string in the method. The model is null, the error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: You will have to post your code so we can see it and help you understand.

Comment: Thank you...Will post tomorrow. Very late!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo passing a model containing another one

```
   public class ParentModel
    {
        public ChildModel ChildModel { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
    public class ChildModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ParentModel model = new ParentModel();
            model.Name = "Parent model";
            model.ChildModel = new ChildModel();
            model.ChildModel.Name = "Child Name";

            return View(model);
        }
        public ActionResult SearchMethod (ParentModel model)
        {
            var name = model.Name;
            var childName = model.ChildModel.Name;
            return View(model);
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }
 }
```

The view:

```
@model MVCModelDemo.Models.ParentModel //Note the model passed to the view here
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchMethod", "Home", new { area = "" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.ChildModel.Name)
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
}
```

I hope this can help you understanding the relationships between models, controllers and views